# Problems with using maven plugin

Tags: java, swing, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to use  Maven 2 IDEA UI Designer Plugin. I've edited pom.xml according to this article: http://glxn.net/2010/08/17/making-a-swing-project-using-intellij-idea-and-gui-builder-with-maven-including-executable-jar/
jar file is created ok but when I trying to run it it says:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

```
com/jgoodies/forms/layout/FormLayout
    at MainForm.$$$setupUI$$$(MainForm.java)
    at MainForm.<init>(MainForm.java:14)
    at Main.main(Main.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jgoodies.forms.layout.FormLayout
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 3 more
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>DOC</groupId>
    <artifactId>DOC</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intellij</groupId>
            <artifactId>forms_rt</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- TEST SCOPE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>ideauidesigner-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>javac2</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                    ...
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please add following dependency in your pom.xml and build again.

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>jgoodies</groupId>
     <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.5</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: @SergeyScopin - how are you trying to run your application?

Comment: java -jar name_of_application.jar

Comment: Oh, I created it without dependencies. Works now. Thanx.

Comment: what do you mean by adding the dependencies? I have the same issue. I've included the forms_rt-5.0.jar into the jar file and in the manifest. I uses java -jar myjarfile.jar to run it. it says 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/uiDesigner/core/GridLayoutManager

Comment: I noticed when using "make" in the intelliJ idea (version 14), it makes extra "com/intellij/uiDesigner/core" classes into the target classes directory. The javac2 does not create those classes.